# Align an object to a specific face

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I usually face this problem when I cut objects to make them printable in my 3D printer. As you may know, you need your object to have a nice base to be printed.

So I usually use bisect to cut an object to different pieces. As in this example:

[image: Object bisected]

and I need to rotate the top part to have a face as bottom:

[image: Final Object]

I'll share my workflow in an answer, but I'm asking for a simpler solution, if there were any.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So this is my workflow:

First select the face you want to be the ground of the object, and create a custom *Transform Orientation* from the N panel:

[image: Custom transformation]

Then select the new orientation and place 3D Cursor at the face center with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, *Cursor to Selected*. You could also move object center to the same place with  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*>Object to 3D Cursor*.

[image: Select custom orientation]

Now add an emtpy and align it to my custom orientation.

[image: added emtpy]  [image: align to transform orientation]  [image: aligned empty]

Now parent the object to the empty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>), clear the empty rotation (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>), and clear the object's parent keeping transformation (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>>...).

[image: parenting] [image: unparenting]

Finally rotate the piece 180º, and you have the face as the ground.

[image: Final]

Answer (score 10):

Try my addon, [Mesh Align Plus](https://github.com/egtwobits/mesh_align_plus) (we align an object in the example below, but you can also do this to a mesh selection or whole mesh):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use vertex snapping to achieve this effect.

Note before we begin: You can activate snapping by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

1. Enable vertex snapping
   [image]
2. Select all the vertices along the edge of the cut face, then with the pivot point set to anything **except** *active element*, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to selected*
3. Set the origin of the mesh to the 3D cursor(<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>>*Origin to 3D cursor*) If you don't want to move the origin,  set the pivit point to 3D cursor.
4. Add a plane in object mode. we will align the mesh to this plane. 
   [image]
5. Now with the mesh selected, hit <kbd>R</kbd>, (lock rotation to the axis of the cut mesh). With snapping turned on, move your cursor over one of the vertices on the plane.

Gif Demo:

[image]

**Edit:**
This will work on multiple axis, first perform the snap on the X then the Y. I will note that it is incredibly difficult to get the snapping right. The best technique is to do the rotation in edit mode with snapping set to active.

Comment: Exactly, you can rotate the mesh using snapping. I will add a .gif demonstrating this to the post in a second.

Comment: Nice one. But as you say, it seems it only works if you cut the object in one of the main views.

Comment: I've been trying to apply this method in Blender 3.0, and I couldn't get it to work. I then figured out that in the little snap options, you need to make sure that "Affect: Rotate" is enabled, and "Align rotation to Target" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Although developed in a fork there is a tool that simplifies this requirement.

It works over selected data, in ob and editmode, and developed as a new  transform tool. It's not and addon. You must specify 1, 2, or 3 points as origin (using snap tool most times), and then the same number of points as destiny. First point is a translation. With the second point it performs and axis match, and with the 3rd point a plane match (rotating over the axis defined).

The project also allows to move the view during transform, which is also great.

https://vimeo.com/161994522

http://www.mechanicalblender.org/features/match-tool.html

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Is it possible you could add a short summary of the linked video, describing how to use the feature? We like answers to be able to stand on their own if linked content becomes unavailable in the future. Thanks