# Restoring object transformation data after execute 'apply' command

Tags: transforms

I have a box and it has been translated,rotated,scaled using random value. If i apply the transformation. Is there any way i can get the data back or how to restore the trasformation value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Script.**

[image]

Grab the [script from here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/121227/15543)

Basically its the rotation that needs to be reset, once it is axis aligned, scaling, translating and moving the origin are trivial.

- Put the object into edit mode.
- Select a face that has a normal and edge aligned to axes.
- Run the script.
- If the selected face didn't axis align, Undo  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>,
  and try with another face.