# Apply face normal orientation to object Local Pivot Point orientation?

Tags: modeling, interface, transforms, shortcut, transform-orientation

Is there a **simple** way to "apply" a custom transform orientation to an objects pivot?

The purpose is to set the faces normal as the new pivot of the object.

Duarte Farrajota Ramos' cube merge trick is fine however it needs a dummy object to work. Efficient but quite time consuming in my opinion.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/121223/75435

[image: blender new pivot from custom orientation steps]

[image: custom orientation Rotation values]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you talking about a pivot point? Your step one is calling the transform orientation a default pivot and step two calls it a custom pivot. These are orientations. Pivot Points are in the dropdown next to the orientations, and the only way to have a custom one of those is to place the cursor where you'd like the pivot to be and choose the Cursor as your pivot.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm talking about orientations, the ability to rotate pivot axis. I know you can set a custom pivot in space from the 3D cursor. After setting a custom orientation : how to apply the requested orientation as a local orientation ?

Comment: *"how to apply the requested orientation as a local orientation"* if you mean you'd like to start new transform along custom orientation after it's created then either you can choose it from the dropdown menu of orientation in the viewport header *or* just after creating orientation check *Use After Creation* option in the Last operator panel in the viewport (in 2.79 checkbox was enabled by default, in 2.8, well, appears isn't)

Comment: @MrZak Thank you for your suggestion for this very useful option however I am talking about another problem. The wording is confusing. I added an image to better understand the purpose of this issue.
Once the custom orientation is created, the XYZ rotation values of the object do not change in the properties panel. These values correspond to the "permanent" local orientation. If a rotation of a specific axis, for example in Z, is performed, all values in XYZ change. This is a real problem when it comes to animating the object.

Comment: I see now. I'm afraid the only solution I know thus far is to use trick with empty aligned to the face to which object is parented, this is described in [another answer there](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63577/1245). In 2.8 3D cursor can have its own rotation which can be used as transform orientation however one thing left is to find a way to snap its rotation to mesh face.

Comment: Since the time I posted this question, a new feature "Affect only origins" allows in a few steps to solve my problem. > How to video
> > https://twitter.com/ThomasCharier/status/1199035164061507584

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to be picky, but just to make asking easier in the future: in Blender the pivot is what you’ve selected to be the point you rotate around. What other software like 3ds Max calls the pivot, in Blender, is called the origin. I think that’s what you’re talking about. This is a serious shortcoming of Blender, the fact that you can’t directly modify the origin. There is an addon called BS Modify Pivot that does what you need. An alternative is that you move and rotate the object to the place you need it to be and then do the opossite move and rotation to the mesh in edit mode.