# How to rotate and align axis inside edit mode

Tags: modeling

[image]

I have a object rotation and position are all zero, but I rotated it in edit mode, now I want to align it to XY plane, how to do it ??

Comment: Check out answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144167/35559)  and  [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144291/35559) .. among the others linked from the questions.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's actually quite complicated :p