# Blender how to set a mesh perpendicular to the grid or ather mesh?

Tags: mesh

I have a rather complex object with several mesches, the problem is that not everything is at right angles (perpendicula) .

The problem is that the parts do not fit neatly on or together.

How can I square (perpendicula) each mes individually (for example on the grid)?
[image]

Comment: maybe try this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144100/is-there-a-way-to-realign-a-not-aligned-object-which-tranforms-has-already-been

Comment: OK, I'm going to try that, it sounds logical