# How to apply all transformations to an object at low level?

Tags: python, transforms, matrix

I am new to Blender (and to some extent to python). 
I have pieced together this function that rotates and scales an Object at low level by modifying the matrices:

```
def rotate_scale_object(inObj, angle, axis, scaling):
        rot_mat = Matrix.Rotation(radians(angle), 4, axis)
        orig_loc, orig_rot, orig_scale = inObj.matrix_world.decompose()
        orig_loc_mat   = Matrix.Translation(orig_loc)
        orig_rot_mat   = orig_rot.to_matrix().to_4x4()
        orig_scale_mat = (Matrix.Scale(scaling,4,(1,0,0)) @ Matrix.Scale(scaling,4,(0,1,0)) @ Matrix.Scale(scaling,4,(0,0,1)))
        # assemble the new matrix
        inObj.matrix_world = orig_loc_mat @ rot_mat @ orig_rot_mat @ orig_scale_mat
        #update_matrices(inObj)
        return inObj
```

I call it in my script as follow:

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
obj = scale_rotate_smooth_color(obj, angle = -90, axis = "X", scaling = 0.01)
```

It works very well: the object is rotated & scaled as expected. 
Yet, I am missing a way to "apply" these transformations to the object, as one would do by pressing `Ctrl + A` and select `Apply all transformations`.

Is there a way to do this "low level", without resorting to `bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will definitively implement it this way.

Comment: obj.data.transform(obj.matrix_world) obj.data.update() matrix = Matrix.Identity(4) obj.matrix_world = matrix

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Mesh transform**

[Does a child object inherit the matrix from the parent?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169416/does-a-child-object-inherit-the-matrix-from-the-parent)

Applying the transform.

- Set the basis matrix value to identity for any or all of location, rotation scale.
- Transform the mesh and or child objects to reflect the change

For all transforms.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
mb = ob.matrix_basis
if hasattr(ob.data, "transform"):
    ob.data.transform(mb)
for c in ob.children:
    c.matrix_local = mb @ c.matrix_local
    
ob.matrix_basis.identity()
```

**To apply only rotation.**

Similarly will show the process of only applying rotation.  Transform the data and children such that the rotation part of matrix basis is identity.

Method below uses the `Matrix.decompose` to reduce the transform into its three components.  The rotation is defined as a quaternion.  Another way to decompose is discussed in

[How to Decompose and Compose the local transform matrix](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223800/how-to-decompose-and-compose-the-local-transform-matrix/223804#223804)

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
from mathutils import Matrix

ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world
mb = ob.matrix_basis

loc, rot, scale = mb.decompose()

# rotation
T = Matrix.Translation(loc)
R = rot.to_matrix().to_4x4()
S = Matrix.Diagonal(scale).to_4x4()

if hasattr(ob.data, "transform"):
    ob.data.transform(R)

for c in ob.children:
    c.matrix_local = R @ c.matrix_local
    
ob.matrix_basis = T @ S
```

For rotation and scale

```
...:
    ob.data.transform(R @ S)

for c in ob.children:
    c.matrix_local = (R @ S) @ c.matrix_local
    
ob.matrix_basis = T
```

*ie* set the basis to make identity of applied property, transform mesh and children by the jconverse.  *eg* applying all is transforming by `T @ R @ S` and setting to `I @ I @ I` transform & scale `T @ I @ S` --> `I @ R @ S`  (where `I` is identity matrix)

**Method for all or any**

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

def apply_transfrom(ob, use_location=False, use_rotation=False, use_scale=False):
    mb = ob.matrix_basis
    I = Matrix()
    loc, rot, scale = mb.decompose()

    # rotation
    T = Matrix.Translation(loc)
    #R = rot.to_matrix().to_4x4()
    R = mb.to_3x3().normalized().to_4x4()
    S = Matrix.Diagonal(scale).to_4x4()

    transform = [I, I, I]
    basis = [T, R, S]

    def swap(i):
        transform[i], basis[i] = basis[i], transform[i]

    if use_location:
        swap(0)
    if use_rotation:
        swap(1)
    if use_scale:
        swap(2)
        
    M = transform[0] @ transform[1] @ transform[2]
    if hasattr(ob.data, "transform"):
        ob.data.transform(M)
    for c in ob.children:
        c.matrix_local = M @ c.matrix_local
        
    ob.matrix_basis = basis[0] @ basis[1] @ basis[2]


# test call
apply_transfrom(bpy.context.object, use_rotation=True)
```

Recent answer using `Mesh.transform` [Problem with rotating objects by script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159130/problem-with-rotating-objects-by-script/159146#159146)

Comment: Exactly what I was missing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: cheers, prob should have used mult by inverse instead of setting to identity.  eg  to apply rotation make a rotation matrix, `R` apply it to mesh `me.transform(R)`, then mult matrix_world by `R.inverted()`

Comment: This didn't work for me, which is why I asked another question. But it got closed. I wanted to apply rotations to my meshes after adding rotation eulers. In the end I rewrote my code to perform the rotation directly on the meshes instead of using bpy.ops.

Comment: Apologies, fixed and fixed. Probably relates to comment above also. Edited this one re-opened other.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for the edits!

Comment: @batFINGER your 'rotation only' solution worked brilliantly for me. Thanks very much! Your 'for any' solution didn't work however. I tested it in my class and my rotation gets lost. Might be worth looking into for future problem solving, but I'm happy here with just rotation.

Comment: Meant to mention was considering an option to identity parent inverse. Can you elaborate on setup that  "didn't work"

Comment: @DrewTNBD this one was recently brought to my attention https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223800/how-to-decompose-and-compose-the-local-transform-matrix/223804#223804  may be an option to look at for here.

Comment: @batFINGER so what I did was I took your "for any" solution, and I added a self parameter and shamelessly put it into my class. I called it with use_rotation=True and my rotation wasn't applied at all. But when I did it with your "just rotation" solution, it worked fine. But what I am noticing now is that the bounding box for the object doesn't seem to get recalculated. So when I run a object.bound_box call on the rotated object, it still has the pre-rotation values in it. Which really twists my melon!

Comment: The two examples in question "rotation only" and "all" when run _as above_ both theoretically are same and testing (so far) glean the same result (consistent with op)  for me. Do you get a differing result using _as above_?  Consider re-jigging your question re issue, since it could prob be closed as a dupe of this one now. (my re-opening prior, excludes me from voting to close again)  Depending on use, a `Mesh.update()` or `ViewLayer.update()`  may be required

Comment: to be sure, there is no way to apply scale in edit mode? and get it back, for instance, after having moved the origin?

Comment: @batFINGER first of all - thank you for this function which proved to do the job perfectly for me :) If I could just ask you - is it possible to improve it, so it can handle negative values as well? For example I have an object with scale X = -1 to mirror it along X. Big thanks!