# Does a child object inherit the matrix from the parent?

Tags: parent, matrix

When you create a hierarchy with nesting like so:

[image]

Does `Circle` inherit the properties from the parent matrix? Or is first the matrix of `Cirlce.001` applied followed by the matrix of `Circle`?

You can't tell by the values in the editor since it could subtract with the parent values.
So hopefully a programmer can answer me this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Basics of Local and Global Coordinate systems**

Each object in blender has a number of matrices. Its global transform matrix `ob.matrix_world` its local space matrix `ob.matrix_local`.  The basis matrix `ob.matrix_basis`, this is what you see in the "editor" 
[image]

and its parenting matrix `ob.matrix_parent_inverse` (*This is set when choosing parenting Keep Offset for example*)

Relation between basis and local

```
ob.matrix_local = ob.matrix_parent_inverse @ ob.matrix_basis
```

As an example, select an object and calculate its global matrix by going up the hierarchy chain.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
M = Matrix()
print(ob.matrix_world)
while ob.parent:
    M = (ob.matrix_parent_inverse @ ob.matrix_basis) @ M
    ob = ob.parent

M = ob.matrix_basis @ M

print(M)
```

similarly

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
M = Matrix()
print(ob.matrix_world)
while ob.parent:
    M = ob.matrix_local @ M
    ob = ob.parent

M = ob.matrix_local @ M

print(M)
```

Result on test case, Cube is parent of Cube.001 is parent of Cube.002 some random transforms applied to each.

[image]

```
<Matrix 4x4 ( 0.3256, -0.9107,  0.8122, -3.8782)
            (-0.6125, -0.9379, -0.8588, -6.2457)
            ( 1.5886,  0.1065, -0.9282,  4.2578)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 ( 0.3256, -0.9107,  0.8122, -3.8782)
            (-0.6125, -0.9379, -0.8588, -6.2457)
            ( 1.5886,  0.1065, -0.9282,  4.2578)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>
```

Comment: Awesome explanation!