# Object hierarchy - scale does not change location

Tags: transforms

I am importing a DAE file which has objects in a hierarchy.

When I change the first object in the hierarchy's scale (reducing by a scale factor of 1000), the object becomes smaller to the size I would like.

However, when I view the XYZ location of an object lower in the hierarchy, the dimension scale change, but the location does not. Why is this?

Example:

Before doing anything. Note the Location XYZ
[image]

Original scale factor of top level object:
[image]

I have now changed the scale for the top level object to a scale of .001:
[image]

I'm selecting the object a few down the hierarchy again. As you can see the dimensions of the object changed, but the location XYZ does not change.

[image]

Comment: To be clear, you are asking why an object's location doesn't change when you scale it?

Comment: @person132 - Yes.

Comment: I am fairly certain that this would not be the expected behavior. Position and scale are two separate properties of objects, and changing one shouldn't affect the other one.

Comment: The position shouldn't change, but the decimal place should. It's currently 206m away from the previous object, when it's size is .2m.

Comment: Further to the answer of lemon below,see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169424/15543  So for any child object what we see in transform panel is somewhat arbitrary, and not global coordinates. The scene cursor displays global coordinates,.  To reflect changes down a hierarchy  consider apply scale ctrl-A of the base making it unit (1, 1, 1) scale for current size.  scaling  descendants,  do again for children etc, resulting in all parts having a uniform unit scale.  Some importers have a scale option to do this for us,  not dae by the looks.

Comment: @batFINGER - That would cause the objects to be uniform in size, but not the correct size. I'm working on a robot file that will reflect a real life robot. So all dimensions in Blender need to match the real world.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the parenting and an expected result.

When a child appears scaled due to its parent scale, the child **own** coordinates, scale or rotation won't change.

That's allow, when unparenting <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, to have the choice between *"clear parent"* and *"clear and keep transform"*.

Internally, Blender keeps the object **own** coordinates in `matrix_basis` and the **resulting** coordinates of its dependencies in `matrix_world`.

Also, moving the parented object by x unit will result in a move of its **own** coordinates of x unit times the inverse of the scale given by its parent. So, all is coherent.

If you want to keep parenting with scales and locations being applied, select all the parts and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to apply, then *"scale"*.

Comment: It seems that using the Alt + P "clear parent" and "clear and keep transform" option does correct the location XYZ scale, but it removes all hierarchy. I need to maintain hierarchy and get the correct XYZ location. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, select them all and apply scale (ctrl A then scale)