# Parenting and animating Bone to an empty without going to pose mode

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, parent

So I wanted to parent an empty to a bone, so i can pose/animate the bone without going to pose mode.

is there a way to do this ?

So when i move the empty in object mode, the bone will follow and following with IK

[image]

Comment: That’s not parenting the empty to the bone, but as you said using IK or possibly a track-to constraint on the bone with an empty as a target. Parenting the empty to the bone, thus the empty is the child, would make the empty follow the bone around instead.

Comment: @Fernaldy Wiranata, so what you want is more parenting the bone to the empty  ;)  have you tried a Child Of constraint? But actually you don't tell a lot about your current rigging

Comment: If you want to be able to pose the character and still be able to select and maniputale other objects in the scene without going back and forth between object mode and pose mode you can just go to the top menu and go in Edit > lock object modes (uncheck it), than you will still be able to select everything even when in pose mode.

It's not a direct answer to your question but might help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say @ZargulTheWizard has summed it up pretty well.  It's a very convenient way to manipulate limbs etc with few if any restrictions.

Everything is IK'd as normal but (as mentioned above in the comments) the target as selected in the IK's "Target" slot is your Empty.  Dragging the Empty will force the bone to "look at", (track it), but not be attached to it.

[image]

This method allows hands to appear to be holding objects when in fact they're not.  They are instead, tracking the object that's being animated, e.g.  when throwing a basketball.

[image]

Empties for both arms can be parented to the ball (empties = child) so hands not only appear to throw it, but additionally track it momentarily after it's launched.

Because the Empties are external to the rig and therefore independant, they can themselves be parented to the ball but each kept to one side so hands don't penetrate the ball's surfaces.

The Empties can in other instances, be parented to a character's "Master" Nav(igation)-Empty, along with the armature, so all will move as one unit when the Nav-Empty is dragged around the scene and yet still able to similtaneously move arms and legs.