# Change parent only location via script

Tags: python, parent

```
import bpy

ts = bpy.context.scene.tool_settings
ts.use_transform_skip_children = True
target_loc = bpy.data.objects["target"].location
bpy.context.selected_objects[0].location = target_loc
```

I'm trying to move only the parent to a new location taken from another object in Blender 2.93. The problem I'm having is that the children are moving along eventhough I'm enabling "Affect Only Parent" and I would like to keep the children in its original location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GLOBAL vs LOCAL**

*Similarly to your new question, re rotation, the space is important*

[Does a child object inherit the matrix from the parent?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169416/does-a-child-object-inherit-the-matrix-from-the-parent)

The values we see in UI are the objects `matrix_basis` and when parenting is involved can be somewhat arbitrary if taken on their own.

One way to look at this is an objects world matrix is like its GPS location, *ie* no matter where in the world it has one location. LOCAL however is somewhat arbitrary as we can set the `matrix_parent_inverse` such that any `location` is anywhere.

Hence perhaps the simplest way to do this is to copy the children's world matrix, move the parent, reset back.  Often a goto case in blender is to work in global coordinates.  *Note, when changing matrices in script it can be the case they are not updated, in which case call a view layer update. (Was the old scene update pre 2.8)*

Both examples below move the context object to scene camera's location, whilst leaving their children in place.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

cam = scene.camera # our target object for example sake

ob = bpy.context.object # Parent 
    
before = [(o, o.matrix_world.copy()) for o in ob.children]
ob.matrix_world.translation = cam.matrix_world.translation
#context.view_layer.update()
for  o, mw in before:
    o.matrix_world = mw
```

as described in link above, can also alter the local matrices of the children.

Example of moving context -> camera and setting childrens inverse parent matrix such that they remain stationary.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

cam = scene.camera # our target object for example sake

ob = bpy.context.object # Parent
mw = ob.matrix_world 
global_loc = cam.matrix_world.translation
target_local_loc = mw.inverted() @ global_loc   
ob.matrix_world.translation = global_loc

for c in ob.children:
    c.matrix_parent_inverse.translation -= target_local_loc
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, really appreciated.