# Report vertex locations of parented geometry

Tags: python, vertices, parent

How can I  find the vertex locations when the vertices of a cube are controlled by bones of an armature? This parenting thing is causing my regular setup to break.

I found this post, but struggle with applying it, anybody got an idea how to tackle this one?:
[Does a child object inherit the matrix from the parent?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169416/does-a-child-object-inherit-the-matrix-from-the-parent)

```
# Cube, verts are controlled with hooks / empties
target_object = 'Cube'

def vertex_loc_iter():
        target = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(target_object)
        vertices = target.data.vertices
        for vertex in vertices:
            localmatrix = vertex.co
            worldmatrix = target.matrix_world
            location = worldmatrix @ localmatrix
            yield location
    
for vertex in vertex_loc_iter():
    print ('vertex', vertex)
```

Comment: I suspect rewriting the matrices part would solve this, but so far my matrices trial and error rewrites haven't paid off.