# What is a low level replacement for bpy.ops.object.transform_apply()?

Tags: python, bmesh

I've got this code:

```
            object.location.x += self.parameters.pos_x
            object.location.y += self.parameters.pos_y
            object.location.z += self.parameters.pos_z
            object.rotation_euler = (self.parameters.rot_x, self.parameters.rot_y, self.parameters.rot_z)
            object.select_set(True)
            # Optimization opportunity here
            bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False)
            object.select_set(False)
```

I would like to replace the call to:

```
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False)
```

I figured I would have to use the bmesh module in some way, but I cannot figure out how to do this. I want to apply rotation to all objects in a list.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html) and the [mathutils](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html).

Comment: Someone closed this as a duplicate, but the proposed solution didn't work for me, which is why I asked the question.

In the end I rewrote my code to avoid using rotation_euler. Instead I used bmesh and rotation matrices to perform my rotation directly upon the mesh.

I think the question was closed prematurely though.

Comment: There's also [Mesh.transform](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.transform).

Comment: @scurest closed as a dupe of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159538/how-to-apply-all-transformations-to-an-object-at-low-levelt  As it turns out answer  required correcting, . Re-opened this one.