# How to align face to face

Tags: snapping

I have face snapping on. Instead of snapping face to face the mesh rotating and moving here and there. Any addon or good way to align face to face. Which work perfect and easy way. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This should be rather easy.

1. Enable *Face Snapping > Median* (to snap with origin)
2. Check *Align rotation to target*
3. The object's Z+ axis now aligns to face normals

[image]

Comment: Thank. I tried it its not working. I have attach my model in question.

Comment: @atek May I ask you to accept the answer? I would say it is correct, right? Thank you

Comment: @vklidu. its not working on my mesh. file attach. The above answer it has to many faces. And my mesh have a small mesh of hexagon that i want to snap and align to it.

Comment: @atek It doesn't work because you applied rotation after you tilted the object. Once you correct the orientation back, it works just fine :).

Comment: @JachymMichal can u plz show using my file how it works.

Comment: Local Transform Orientation from face https://twitter.com/ThomasCharier/status/1199035164061507584

Comment: @vklidu That's it! By far the fastest way, thanks for sharing :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Ha ... its even easier by snapping origin directly :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/191225/2214

Comment: @JachymMichal are you saying that once a mesh has been rotated, snap to face will never align with the face's normal  until the mesh has been un-rotated?

Comment: @Reahreic That is correct, when using the origin point for snapping :).