# How to convert vertices rotation to object rotation?

Tags: mesh, transforms, linked-data

I have two monkeys with exactly the same meshes.
They have same objects rotations, but different vertices rotations.

How I can link their meshes with saving rotations?

I think I need to convert the rotation somehow

I also found a script that can revert monkey's rotation ([Script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/121227)).
Maybe I should somehow get the rotation delta after executing the script and apply it to the rotation of the object.

There is a first monkey transforms

[image: First monkey]

And there is a second
[image: Second monkey]

This happens when I link second monkey's mesh to first
[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "How I can link their meshes with saving rotations"? If you want the second object to be exactly the same you can copy the Object Data of the first one

Comment: Yes, I want to copy the Object Data, but second monkey was rotated in edit mode and their meshes are different. When I'm trying to copy Object Data then rotation resets

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh, I think I got it. Here is the script. Not best solution I sure, but it works.

You just need to select the face that will look up at zero rotation. Then just execute the script and it will convert rotations)

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
import logging

context = bpy.context
ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)


face = bm.select_history.active
o = face.calc_center_median()
face.normal_update()
norm = face.normal
edges = sorted((e for e in face.edges), key=lambda e: abs((e.verts[1].co - e.verts[0].co).dot(face.normal)))
e = edges[0]
# if this value is 0 then edge and normal orthogonal should test
print((e.verts[1].co - e.verts[0].co).dot(face.normal))
T = Matrix.Translation(-o)
up = Vector((0, 0, 1))
R = face.normal.rotation_difference(up).to_matrix()

R_inv = R.inverted().to_4x4()

loc = ob.location.copy()

bmesh.ops.transform(bm, verts=bm.verts, matrix=R, space=T)
forward = Vector((0, 1, 0))
R = (e.verts[1].co - e.verts[0].co).rotation_difference(forward).to_matrix()

#bmesh.ops.transform(bm, verts=bm.verts, matrix=R, space=T)
T = Matrix.Translation(face.calc_center_median() - o)
bmesh.ops.transform(bm, verts=bm.verts, matrix=T)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='GEOMETRY_ORIGIN', center='MEDIAN')

ob.matrix_world = R_inv
ob.location = loc
```