# Is there a way to orient an object to my view?

Tags: modeling, objects

I am wondering if there is a way to orient an object to my viewing rotation? I have a slope that I want to place things on, this slope was made by hand so I don't know the exact X and Z rotation. I can make my view look at it from the top down with `shift + 7`, is there a way to make my selected object take this same rotation? the rotation on the sloped object isn't applied yet, does that make a difference? [image]

Comment: Is the local coordinate system of this object aligned to its mesh faces?

Comment: Euhm... maybe? How do I check?

Comment: Do you want only to orient it? Without moving? You could set it as active camera and then use Align Camera to View option but that will move object to wherever viewpoint is

Comment: My intent is to make the small highlighted object in the picture be at the same Y-rotation as the slope below it in order for me to easily just move it down instead of trying to make the rotation somewhat the same from the front viewing angle which is never 100%

Comment: Somewhat related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14232/align-an-object-to-a-specific-face. It's overkill in some steps but should work. Instead of creating custom transform orientation you can use Snapping during transform with Face as target type and enable Align Rotation to the right from the snapping menu to align empty