# How to align object pivot to selected points or edges?

Tags: modeling

In the image on the left, I have selected two points and their pivot is positioned and rotated the way I need it

How can I make the object pivot align as well?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom orientation.

1. Select some vertices and your desired orientation (*Normal* in this case)
2. Add it as a custom orientation through *Transform Orientation menu >* **+**
3. Your custom orientation will now apply to all objects (you can change it in the list)

[image]

Comment: I did just that. got the picture on the right.
but the local origin is rotated incorrectly,  the image on the right shows (I need it to be rotated relative to the two selected points or edges)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I edited the answer :).

Comment: if the edge (between two selected points) is not parallel to any world axis? (in this case, the 3d cursor does not rotate relative to the common normal of the two points)...
how to align the 3d cursor relative to this edge?

that's the question... I understood how to place the cursor somewhere and then change the local origin
I'm sorry, I guess I can't make my question clear

Comment: No problem :). Please try to rephrase your original question, so it's more clear. Do you want to move *object pivot point*, or the *3D cursor*? Also, please specify what you mean by *align 3D cursor relative to edge*.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the updated image right away. The method you specified suits me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Happy to help :). You can now mark the answer as accepted **✓** so others can find it easily.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Sd_1DQCBqtk

with your help, I was able to do what I wanted. but I don't know if the best way is out or if there is a shorter way.

regarding my original question - I wanted to get an object origin that is aligned relative to any points or edges or polygons. to put the object on the plane as a result.

Comment: Hey there :). I'm afraid snapping in Blender is seriously underdeveloped. Here is an [older Blender thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14232/78972) and it seems there isn't a better way currently. Good luck with your project, anyway.

Comment: ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍ thank you again! I couldn't have figured it out without your help, and it took me a long time to find a solution. Good luck!