# Object orientation based on face

Tags: transform-orientation

How do I match the orientation of the half cylinder with the orientation of the rectangle (they should both face the same direction).

[image: face]
[image: face]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6369/how-to-align-an-object-by-one-or-two-edges-to-xyz-axes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14232/align-an-object-to-a-specific-face https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63506/set-object-local-axis-based-on-face-orientation